# Javascript Image Filters in Html Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and html, and I'm having trouble adding a javascript filter function to call when a checkbox is selected. I have all the elements I need, I just need assistance putting it all together. I got this method from (http://www.storminthecastle.com/2013/04/06/how-you-can-do-cool-image-effects-using-html5-canvas/). I am intentionally staying away from doing this through css filter attribute. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap">
     <img src="../images/travel.gif" id="img_prev" width="450" height="450" />
       <h3 class="desc">"Perfection is not attainable, but if we chase perfection we can catch excellence."</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sepia_slider">
    <input id="sepia" type="checkbox" oninput="filterCanvas(this);" value="sepia"> <span style="color:#B78753">Sepia </span>
</div>

<div id="grayscale_slider">
    <input id="grayscale" type="checkbox" oninput="setGrayscale(this);" value="grayscale"> <span style="color:gray">Grayscale </span>
</div>
```

Javascript From Link

```
 var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      if (image.width != canvas.width)
        canvas.width = image.width;
      if (image.height != canvas.height)
        canvas.height = image.height;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      filterCanvas(imageFilter);
    }
    image.src = imageURL;
  }

var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function filterCanvas(filter) {
if (canvas.width > 0 && canvas.height > 0) {
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
filter(imageData);
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
}

grayscale = function (pixels, args) {
var d = pixels.data;
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
var r = d[i];
var g = d[i + 1];
var b = d[i + 2];
d[i] = d[i + 1] = d[i + 2] = (r+g+b)/3;
}
return pixels;

sepia = function (pixels, args) {
var d = pixels.data;
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
var r = d[i];
var g = d[i + 1];
var b = d[i + 2];
d[i]     = (r * 0.393)+(g * 0.769)+(b * 0.189); // red
d[i + 1] = (r * 0.349)+(g * 0.686)+(b * 0.168); // green
d[i + 2] = (r * 0.272)+(g * 0.534)+(b * 0.131); // blue
}
return pixels;
};
```

The image that the filter should be applied to is `class="img_prev"`
Sorry for messy code, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use HTML for this. To use the code that the website gave you need to add the SRC and width/height (Preferably just one so you dont squash the image!) in **Javascript** - the code that you provided us with.

Read up on how image works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

```
 var image = new Image(200,200);
    image.onload = function () {
      if (image.width != canvas.width)
        canvas.width = image.width;
      if (image.height != canvas.height)
        canvas.height = image.height;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      filterCanvas(imageFilter);
    }
    image.src = "../images/travel.gif";
  }
```

That code should make it work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the img_prev class I have already set up? There's alot of code that revolves around this image and it's description. (Maybe I can omit the creation of an image and just apply the filter to my image?)

Comment: There's definitely  a way to do that (If not multiple ways) Im not 100% sure if this would work but just make `var image = getElementById("Img_prev");`

Comment: I'll try that, Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, but it could be because I'm doing something else incorrectly..

Comment: Hmm. Maybe call the filterCanvas function in javascript instead of html.

Comment: Is there a way to assign image.src to the img_prev ID instead of the set image? The image changes based on user upload.

Comment: `image.src = document.getElementById("img_prev").src`

Comment: Console is stating that `canvas` and `context` are not defined. Any ideas?